# Itô-isometry in the extended case?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

It is shown when constructing the Itô-integral that if:

$E[\int_0^T X_t^2dt]< \infty$. Then we have that Itô-isomtry:

$E[\int_0^T X_t^2dt]=E[(\int_o^TX_tdB_t)^2]$.

In the extended Itô integral, we relax the assumtion that $E[\int_0^T X_t^2dt]< \infty$, and instead have that: $P(\int_0^T X_t^2dt< \infty)=1$. If we are in this case, and not in the first case we have that: $E[\int_0^T X_t^2dt]= \infty$.

But I am wondering if we have the Itô-isometry in the extended case as well?(Where both sides must now be infinity?) I have only seen the Itô-isometry proved in the elementary $L^2$-setting.

A way to frame my question is this:, we know that we have the implication $E[\int_0^T X_t^2dt]< \infty \rightarrow E[(\int_o^TX_tdB_t)^2] <\infty$. **But do we have the other implication?**

Here is what I mean:

**Part 1(this one is clear): $E[\int_0^T X_t^2dt]< \infty$**
Now we know that:

$E[(\int_o^TX_tdB_t)^2=E[\int_0^T X_t^2dt]< \infty$

**Part 2: $E[(\int_o^TX_tdB_t)^2]<\infty$**

If we know that $E[(\int_o^TX_tdB_t)^2]<\infty$, as an extended Itô-integral, do we know that we are in the elementary setting and that also $E[\int_0^T X_t^2dt]< \infty$? Or can we have the case that $P(\int_0^T X_t^2dt< \infty)=1 , E[\int_0^T X_t^2dt]= \infty$, and $E[(\int_o^TX_tdB_t)^2]<\infty$, where the last is an Itô-integral in the extended case?

**My attempt of proof:**
When I tried proving this I use that in the extended case instead of $L^2$-convergence of simple functions, we have convergence in probability. By taking subsequences we are working with convergence almost surely. So I have a sequence of simple functions such that $\int_o^T|\phi_n-X_t|^2dt\rightarrow 0$ a.s. And $\int_o^T\phi_ndB\rightarrow \int_0^TX_tdB$ a.s. We know that we can use the Itô-isometry on the simple functions, so we have that $E[(\int_o^T\phi_ndB)^2]=E[\int_0^T\phi_n^2dt]$. But in order to finish I need that $E[\int_0^T\phi_n^2dt]\rightarrow E[\int_0^T X_t^2dt]$, and that $E(\int_o^T\phi_ndB)^2 \rightarrow E(\int_o^TX_tdB)^2$. But since we started with a.s.-convergence and not $L^2$-convergence, I can't see that we have this.

Any ideas? Do you know if the statement holds?

Comment: I suggest you have a look at lemma 3 (the iff part of the assertion) here : https://almostsure.wordpress.com/2010/03/29/quadratic-variations-and-the-ito-isometry/ Unless mistaken it does the trick. Best regards.

Comment: @TheBridge Thank you, it seems to be the case yes, because in the notation of the link we have that $E[X_0]^2=0<\infty$? But I assume we must have that $[X]=\int_0^TX_t^2dt$?

Comment: I also reccomend that you put this in an answer, so I am able to give you the bounty.

Comment: You are interested in the claim square integrability of a local martingale ( a stochastic integral with respect of BM is a local martingale if it exists which is an assumption in your context) entails integrability of quadratic variation (i.e. $ E[(\int_o^TX_tdB_t)^2]<\infty$). The lemma also gives you the other way around in which you are less interested. For the L^2 property of $X_0$ it comes from the fact that the property is not restricted to continuous local martingale in which case the quadratic variation at time 0 equals X_0 if I remember well (have look at Protter's book on this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by you, I put my comment as an answer.

I suggest you have a look at lemma 3 (the iff part of the assertion) [here](https://almostsure.wordpress.com/2010/03/29/quadratic-variations-and-the-ito-isometry/) .

Best regards.

Comment: I am getting very confused at the moment. I have seen several answers to this question with the opposite conclusions.
In J.M Steeles book "Stochastic Calculus and Financial Applications" we have an exercise (12.1) where you are supposed to construct a counterexample to the statement here. Also here on Stack Exchange there are some counterexamples given.

But I cannot see anything wrong in the proof in the "almost sure" blog linked to above either. Maybe I am just tired. What am I missing here?

Comment: Well what you ask is not totally clear to me. What is said in lemma 3 is that X is a L^2 martingale <=>X_0 and [X] are integrable. As a consequence X^2-[X] is a true martingale and then Ito's isometry is true. If X is not a L^2 martingale then you can have exception to Ito's isometry. I think that is what your exercise 12.1 is about. I would then begin to look for strict local martingales as they are not L^2 martingales by hypothesis and so there might be some chance for Ito's isometry to fail. Regards

Comment: Thanks, yes, the lemma is clear. What confuses me is the original question "But do we have the other implication?" asked in the original question above. The answer seems to be "no", to me.
To apply lemma 3 we need to know that stochastic integral process is a L^2 martingale. And this does not seem to follow from the finiteness of the squared expectation of the integral process up to T.